# VBAvalues from multidimensional array into specific range

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

My array has four columns of data.
I would like to paste one full row into Excel. (Not entire array at once though)

Currently I'm doing it with 4 lines of code, but I suspect there might be a simple one-liner code instead.

```
        Cells(i, 1).Value = myArry(i, 1)
        Cells(i, 2).Value = myArry(i, 2)
        Cells(i, 3).Value = myArry(i, 3)
        Cells(i, 4).Value = myArry(i, 4)
```

Could you suggest a simpler solution?
Thank you in advance.

P.s. Edits to the post are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Index` to extract a row (or column) out of a 2D array

```
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Value = Application.Index(myArry, i)
```

Comment: Oooh - I like!  (Need to be careful that the array is dimensioned `1 To xx` though, so that it doesn't default to `0 To xx`.)

Comment: @YowE3K thanks.  code still works with `0` based arrays.  But I always use `(Re)Dim (Lower To Upper ...)` to be explicit and use Lower bound of `1` when the array will be moved to a range

Comment: @YowE3K, What do you mean? Can you dumb it down a bit for me please?

Comment: @chrisneilsen, Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - code works with zero-based arrays, but `myArry(i, 0)` would be placed in `Cells(i, 1)` and `myArry(i, 1)` would be placed in `Cells(i, 2)`, etc - so for the OP's specific example it would need to be a one-based array.

Comment: @YowE3K yes of course  - just pointing out that in general `Index` will work with `0` based arrays